# MongoDB drop collection, name start with backquote

Tags: mongodb

There is a collection in my MongoDB that im not able to drop. 
**The name of the collection ends with a ` (backquote) character** and I got error when executing the drop command.

```
db.MyCollection`.drop()
```

Error is

```
2017-12-07T07:42:35.711+0000 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Is there any other way of removing or is it here forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`getCollection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/) function.

Example:

```
db.getCollection("MyCollection`").drop();
```